# Вставить значение по индексу во вложенном списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, python-3.5, индексация

Индексы для списка и вложенного списка заданы. Попробовал три способа, но тщетно. Смысл в том,чтобы вставить значения x, y = (78, 90) по индексу 0, 1, так как это делает метод .insert()

```
s = [
    [(12, 32), (123, 32), (54, 27)],
    [(60, 30), (61, 41), (50, 65)]
]

ind = 0
idx = 1
x, y = (78, 90)

for ind in s:
    s.insert(idx, (x, y))
```

В данном случае он вставляет значение по индексу,но удаляет предыдущее значение с этим индексом.

```
s[ind][idx] = (x, y)
```

Это не работает,но хорошо отображает суть вопроса.

```
s.insert((ind, idx), (x, y))
```

Comment: `s[ind].insert(idx, (x, y))` так?

Comment: @extrn да, спасибо. Истина была близка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s[0].insert(1, (x,y))
```

insert() вставляет в одномерный список, поэтому его нужно применять к одномерному списку.